Fresh Sitecore 10.3.1 install on Azure breaking after TDS sync with error - "The path "{E18F4BC6-46A2-4842-898B-B6613733F06F}" was not found."
On a fresh install of Sitecore 10.3.1 using the ARM templates provided by Sitecore, the environment breaks after performing a TDS deploy. Showing the following error:
The path "{E18F4BC6-46A2-4842-898B-B6613733F06F}" was not found.

The ID corresponds with the Devices item located at /sitecore/layout/Devices.
The only solution to this problem I could find was this stackoverflow article
However, the dataprovider config is correct and the *.dat files are also present in our install. I am at a loss for what the solution to this problem can be.

Your problem is no doubt related to the fact that TDS is attempting to query Sitecore's content databases for the items it wants to deploy. And it won't find them, since they now sit in resource files. I believe the reason the dataprovider answer isn't helping you is, that TDS Deploy likely does a "direct to database" deploy of some sort.
Try looking for a switch or configuration that disables something like "turbo deploy" or "fast deploy" or similar.
